# limiting size of binary heap to first N elements

Tags: algorithm, heap

I've been studying binary heaps, and they are obviously a good data structure for a priority queue.  Let's say that my stream of data has millions (N) of records, and I'm periodically interested in the top 1000 (k << N) records by rank.  With enough space, I would just maintain an N-sized binary heap, and each insertion would be O(log N).  What I'd like to do, though, is prune the tree on every insertion, i.e. discard the 1001st element.  It's not obvious to me how to do pruning in less than O(k) time.

(If I were happy with O(k) time for each pruning (and insertion), I'd just maintain an ordered list of k elements, not a heap.)

One idea is to have two parallel heaps, one which keeps mins, the other keeping maxes, where both keep only the top 1000 elements.  It's a bit ugly, though.

Just to clarify, these are my constraints:

- insertion: ideally less than ~1000 ops (so rules out primitive list)
- storage: limited, need to prune unpopular items roughly at rate of insertion (some constant-ish overhead is ok)
- querying top 1000: top 1000 items don't have to be perfectly sorted, heap-ish order is fine

Comment: Can you state your ***question*** a little more clearly? (Hint: questions end in question marks)

Comment: If you prune after every k steps (k = 1000 is the number of items to select) with a selection algorithm, then each insert is O(1). (This is a comment because you specified every step.)

Comment: Basically, it comes down to this:

 - A balanced binary tree is great for a dynamic situation where you want to keep the top 1000 items over time, and you need to query them fairly frequently.
 - A Min-Max heap overcomes some of the limitations of a simple Min-Heap.
 - For a more static situation where you just want to get the top 1000 items from a large dataset, you essentially use an upside-down heap, where the head element is no longer the "best" item, but instead the head element is the gatekeeper to the top 1000, with ordering reversed such that "better" items are deeper down.

Comment: Is it not enough to have a 2047-item binary heap and whenever you add a new item and the heap is already full, just replace the last (2047th) element with the item you are inserting?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this very easily with a binary heap.

Say you have a stream of items of some unknown size, and you want to find the top 1,000 items.  Here's the idea.

```
initialize heap
while (items to be read)
{
    read item
    if (heap.count < 1000 OR item > heap.Peek())
    {
        // Either we haven't added 1,000 items yet,
        // or the new item is larger than the smallest
        // item on the heap.
        heap.Add(item)
        if (heap.count > 1000)
        {
            // trim the heap
            // This makes sure that the heap doesn't
            // grow too large.
            heap.RemoveFirst()
        }
     }
}
```

( `heap.Peek()` examines but does not remove the lowest item on the heap).

When you're done, the heap will contain the top 1,000 items by rank.

This cannot be done in O(N) time. The complexity of this algorithm is O(N log k), where `k` is the size of the heap.

By the way, you won't maintain an ordered list in O(N) time, either.

Another option, if you can keep all 1,000,000 items in an array, is Quickselect. It runs in O(N) time, but I've found that when `k` is small in comparison to `N`, the heap selection technique is faster. See [When theory meets practice](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/) for the details.

If you can't keep all the items in memory (i.e. you're working with a stream of data), then the heap selection technique is the best you can do. You could do the same thing with a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list), which would also be O(n log k), but the skip list might perform slightly better than a binary heap.

By the way, that O(n log k) is the worst case, which would happen if the items were presented to the heap in sorted order. In that case, every item is added to the heap. If items are are distributed more normally, the majority of items don't get past the `heap.Peek()` test. My tests show that with a normal distribution, only about 10% of the items (when selecting 1,000 from 1,000,000) pass that first test. Again, more information is available in the blog post I linked above.

Comment: @Saeed: On a min heap, you can find the smallest item in O(1) time.

Comment: Jim, can you explain how insertion into an ordered list wouldn't be O(N) time?  If I just always keep the top 1000 items, each insert pushes an average of 500 down the list, right?

Comment: @Saeed: I really meant min heap. This really isn't complicated. The idea of using a min heap to select the k largest items is a well-known solution that's been around for a very long time. You want to use a min heap because finding the smallest item (which you need to test and potentially remove) is O(1). If you used a max heap, finding the smallest element would be O(log k).

Comment: @Jim, I agree with you that a min heap can be used to pull k top items fairly efficiently, but the problem with the min heap is how to keep it from growing in size too far beyond the top k values.

Comment: @SteveHowell: Say you have a list of 1,000 items, and the next 1,000 items have to be inserted into the list. So for every item you insert, on average, you move 500 items. So the total number of items moved is 1,000 * 500, which is (n^2)/2. If you were to use an ordered list for selection, the algorithm would be O(n * k).

Comment: @SteveHowell: That's the point of the code that I wrote. First, it only inserts an item if it's larger than the smallest item already on the heap. Second, whenever it inserts an item (beyond the first k items), it prunes the heap by removing the smallest item.

Comment: Ok I see that now, at first it wasn't clear to me what is your heap type.

Comment: Jim, I think we were measuring different things.  If I were to keep an ordered list, each insert would be O(k), so you are correct that N inserts would O(n * k).

Comment: Jim, the only problem with your solution is that the heap's sort of upside down.  If I regular wanted to query the largest item, then that would be expensive.  (In my original posting, that was the idea behind having two heaps.  One heap would make it easy to keep track of the "best" items in conventional order; the other heap would make it easy to identify items falling out of the top 1000.)

Comment: @SteveHowell: You didn't specify that you needed to keep the items that fell out. If you want to do that, then you'd need an additional data structure. As for the heap being backwards, you could copy the underlying array and reverse it (an O(k) operation) if you really need the items in some kind of order. Be aware, though, that the  heap can become very unbalanced (small items at the leaves) so "heap-ish" order wouldn't do you much good. In general, a heap is a terrible data structure for querying. If you need to query, then a skip list (preferable) or balanced tree would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need a [Min-Max heap](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/mike/Papers/MinMaxHeaps/MinMaxHeaps.pdf).

That gives you O(log(n)) operations for both delete min and delete max, which should help you achieve your goal.

Comment: -1 would you clarify how you want keep top 1000 elements with min-max heap?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, Create a min-max heap with first 1000 elements.  For each element `x` thereafter, if `x > heap.min` delete `heap.min` and add `x` to heap.  End up with top 1000 elements in heap; to withdraw them in order, extract `heap.max` 1000 times.

Comment: Peter, the Min-Max paper is great.  I believe this exactly answers my question.  Thanks!

Comment: @jwpat7, really I can't understand you want find what? assume k=2 and you have a list of 10 item, try what you want to do with pen and paper.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, suppose n=7, k=3, x=(7,3,4,8,1,5,6).  Init h with 7,3,4 to {7,3,4}.  Test 8>3, del 3, add 8, h={8,7,4}.  Test 1>4. Test 5>4, del 4, add 5, h={8,7,5}.  Test 6>5. Del 5, add 6.  h={8,7,6}.

Comment: Whereas this solves the problem, I don't understand why you'd need a min-max heap when a simple min heap solves the problem quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Heap is not good for searching items, and it doesn't preserve order of elements to keep first 1000 elements, you can do this with [balanced binary search tree](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/collections/BinarySearchTree.aspx) in O(n).

**Edit:** Also Idea of using min heap to get biggest item is fine enough, and I wasn't aware of that, but I prefer BST.

Comment: What? Of course you can do this with a heap. It's a standard heap selection algorithm. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Selecting_k_smallest_or_largest_elements. And, although you can do this with a balanced binary search tree in O(n) time, it takes O(n log n) to build the tree.

Comment: @Jim Mischel, your referenced link refers to selection algorithm and it's not related to heap, also for creating balanced search tree of k top node from n element it takes O(n log k) not O(n log n), and because k in OPs question is not big, logK is constant (here 10). and I offered this, because it's very simpler than selection algorithm, specially with available classes in different languages.

Comment: You really need to read that linked article. It specifically mentions using a heap, "Another simple method is to add each element of the list into an ordered set data structure, such as a **heap** or self-balancing binary search tree". Yes, a heap and a balanced binary tree can both be built in O(n log k). But building a heap is faster than building a balanced binary tree (smaller constant factors). Removing the smallest item from either takes O(log k) time. But *finding* the smallest item in a heap is O(1), whereas it's O(log k) in a binary tree.

Comment: Also, your answer says that this can be done in O(n) time with a balanced tree. That's incorrect. It can be done in O(n) time once the tree is built.

Comment: I am downvoting this, because a heap works great for being able to get the 1000 top items on ad hoc basis.  The constraint here is storage.  The key part of the question is pruning.

Comment: @JimMischel, binary tree of size K can be constructed in O(n) if k is small enough (in fact is n logK), About reference I first think you want to say selection algorithm, but I see what you wanna to say, i guess this is wrong (see my comment on your answer) and I'll edit wiki or I'll left comment to edit it, first i should be sure, If you see this part of wiki doesn't have any reference.

Comment: @Steve Howell, I'm using O(k) in this case O(1000) storage, and heap storage is also O(k) and with heap you can't do as fast as this.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri The wording of your answer threw me off a bit.  When you said "heap is not good for searching items," I think you are just saying that it doesn't easily point you to the 1001st element, which I agree with.

Comment: @SteveHowell: If you add an item to a min heap that already has 1,000 items on it, the 1001st item is then the smallest item on the heap--the root of the tree. Removing the smallest item is one of the basic operations. It can be located in O(1) time (thus `heap.Peek`), and it can be removed in O(log k) time.

Comment: @Saeed: It does not require a heap of size 2,048 to hold 1,025 items. It can be done with only 1,025 storage locations, just as a binary tree can be. After all, a heap and a balanced binary tree are just different organizations of the general binary tree structure.

Comment: @Jim Mischel, seems you are excellent in heap concept, but after finding top 1000 item with BST, you have an sorted tree and also it can be useful in dynamic search during insertions. but in all now I accept that heap is faster here (a little), If the usage is just finding 1000 items.